# Inkscape cli: select all text objects filled with a specific color and align all to bottom

Tags: inkscape

I have a svg file that contains many text objects filled with the color `0070c0`. It contains also other objects.

I would like, via CLI, to select only those text objects with that fill, and then vertically align them all to bottom of the page.

I have tried to select those using this command, but I cannot select using the `fill=#0070c0` parameter

```
inkscape --actions="select-by-selector:text;select-invert;delete;export-plain-svg;export-filename:out.svg;export-do" input.svg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, in Inkscape,  `select-by-selector` has some limitations (see this for [details](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/3070)). however, you can use `lxml` module in Python or any other tool to get the IDs of the text elements with a specific fill color. Then we can use Inkscape actions to align the text elements.

1. The following Python script `get_ids.py` extracts the IDs of text elements with a specific fill color:

**`get_ids.py`**:

```py
from lxml import etree

# Change the input filename
tree = etree.parse("input.svg")
namespaces = {'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'}

# Change the fill color
elements = tree.xpath("//svg:text[contains(@style, 'fill:#0000ff')]/@id", namespaces=namespaces)

print(','.join(elements))
```

Make sure you have lxml installed with:

```
python3 -m pip install lxml
```

2. Use inkscape CLI to align the text elements with the bottom of the page:

In Unix-like shells such as bash:

```
inkscape --actions="select-by-id:$(python3 get_ids.py); object-align: bottom  page;export-do" input.svg
```

On Windows using Powershell (I haven't tested it but it should work):

```
$id = python get_ids.py
inkscape --actions="select-by-id:$id;object-align:bottom page;export-do" input.svg
```

### Result:

**Before**:

[image: Before alignment]

**After**:

[image: After alignment]

Comment: Really a great answer, it works!